# Is it possible to use mysql database without installation?

Tags: mysql

I have already installed eclipse for java/j2ee. For learning purposes, I want some database to be available in my system. I don;t have admin rights. So without installation I want to use the database. Is it possible to use mysql in this case?

Comment: Not unless it's already installed and you have been granted rights on a database schema.  It might be possible for you to install your own copy of MySQL under your home directory, but that would require some customization of the config, and probably running on a different port.

Comment: Hi Jim, But I heard, like we can use mysql connector and mysql database to connect with java and db. is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly the same as MySQL, but you *may* be able to set up a [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database. sqlite will allow you to create and maintain a local database, housed in a single file, without needing special SQL permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the noinstall Zip Archive.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-install-archive.html

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be MySQL? You could use an embedded SQL database like derby/javaDB instead. I don't think it's possible with MySQL.

Comment: can i use hibernate with derby or javadb?

Comment: ...or use HSQLDB. I just read that it seems to fit well with hibernate.